# MongoDB Throwing Syntax error while creating Date() in python file

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

When I am running the following command in mongodb shell its is running fine

```
db.abcd_vehiclestate.count({"createdAt" : {"$lt": new Date("2017-03-27T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

but when I am putting that inside a python script its throwing syntax error

```
""testcount = db[col].count({"CreatedAt" : {'$lt':new Date("2017-03-28") }})                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax""
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause `db[col].count({"CreatedAt" : {'$lt':new Date("2017-03-28") }})` is a javascript syntax. You should convert it to python syntax.

Try it:

```
from datetime import datetime

db[col].count({'CreatedAt': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28)}})
```